# where m_fLastX and m_fLastY are initialized in the COpenGLControl class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, mfc, event-handling

Consider the [COpenGLControl class here in codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm). I have uploaded the final class [here](http://www.4shared.com/rar/2Qqy2Sru/COpenGLControl_class.html) for you but you can download it [at the bottom of the webpage Setting Up OpenGL in an MFC Control. the name of the file is BF_oglMFCDialog_Part2.zip](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm) if you're interested.
My question is, you see `m_fLastX` and `m_fLastY` defined in the header of the class:

**OpenGLControl.h**

```
class COpenGLControl : public CWnd
{
    public:
        /******************/
        /* Public Members */
        /******************/
        UINT_PTR m_unpTimer;
        // View information variables
        float    m_fLastX;
        float    m_fLastY;
        float    m_fPosX;
```

but they're not initialized in the constructor of the class and nowhere else but are used in the `OnMouseMove` event handler without initialization:

**OpenGLControl.cpp**

```
COpenGLControl::COpenGLControl(void)
{
    m_fPosX = 0.0f;     // X position of model in camera view
    m_fPosY = 0.0f;     // Y position of model in camera view
    m_fZoom = 10.0f;    // Zoom on model in camera view
    m_fRotX = 0.0f;     // Rotation on model in camera view
    m_fRotY = 0.0f;     // Rotation on model in camera view
    m_bIsMaximized = false;
}  

void COpenGLControl::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    int diffX = (int)(point.x - m_fLastX);
    int diffY = (int)(point.y - m_fLastY);
    m_fLastX  = (float)point.x;
    m_fLastY  = (float)point.y;

    // Left mouse button
    if (nFlags & MK_LBUTTON)
    {
        m_fRotX += (float)0.5f * diffY;

        if ((m_fRotX > 360.0f) || (m_fRotX < -360.0f))
        {
            m_fRotX = 0.0f;
        }

        m_fRotY += (float)0.5f * diffX;

        if ((m_fRotY > 360.0f) || (m_fRotY < -360.0f))
        {
            m_fRotY = 0.0f;
        }
    }

    // Right mouse button
    else if (nFlags & MK_RBUTTON)
    {
        m_fZoom -= (float)0.1f * diffY;
    }

    // Middle mouse button
    else if (nFlags & MK_MBUTTON)
    {
        m_fPosX += (float)0.05f * diffX;
        m_fPosY -= (float)0.05f * diffY;
    }

    OnDraw(NULL);

    CWnd::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

Could you explain me how these uninitialized variables are used without making any error?
In fact what is the algorithm used in `OnMouseMove` function?
Or how does an event handler work different from other functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an error to use uninitialized variables. It will give an indeterminate result, which may lead to logic/arithmetic errors.

Now, in this example it probably does not matter most of the time that `m_fLastX` or `m_fLastY` do not have an initial value because it is rarely the case that the first time an MFC application receives a mouse move event, the user **also** has a mouse button down.

You should go ahead and correct this anyway. I would initialize these two variables to -1.0f (since the CPoint will never contain negative values) and then add some additional logic to the top of OnMouseMove (...):

```
if (m_fLastX < 0.0f && m_fLastY < 0.0f) {
  m_fLastX = (float)point.x;
  m_fLastY = (float)point.y;
}
```

Alternatively, in the constructor you might initialize `m_fLastX` and `m_fLastY` using the value of `GetCursorPos (...)`

In any case, I would not worry about it too much. This will only affect the software the very first time the OpenGL control receives a mouse move event. After that, it will always have an initialized value to use for the purpose of calculating the mouse delta.

The algorithm it employs works by storing the position of the mouse the last time the control was notified that the cursor moved and calculating the difference between it and the current mouse position. It then scales this and applies transformations depending on which button is pressed. It applies rotation (left button), zoom (right buttom) or translation (middle button).

As for MFC event handlers, they are simply object oriented callbacks. MFC hides the internal window message pump and sends events to individual controls using installed event handlers.